# Store and retrieve images and data form JSON to local storage or SD card for Android and iPad App

Tags: json, image, store

I am working on an android app (later will convert to iPad APP) using cordova which is used to show products in different categories. Currently the data and image is pulling from a WordPress posts using JSON. I want to store those images and data to localstorage OR SD card OR database within app for viewing without internet connection (Offline). Can any one help to store and retrieve those data using jQuery or JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

to download the file, you need to use [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/doc/index.md) plugin

Comment: thnx, can u pls explain how can i integrate the plugin with my current coding?

Comment: it depends on what version of cordova are you using.. heres some reference http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

Comment: Thnx again. Im already created the App using cordova. Now i want to store the images and data in a listview for offline view

Comment: you probably should read about data caching instead of downloading everything.

Comment: can u pls give me an example?